# :not (CSS selector) dealing with threaded selectors

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="main-l">
  <table class="tbl">
    ..
  </table>
</div>
```

I am using the following CSS to exclude tables with "main-l tbl" classes:

```
table:not(.main-l .views-table) {
  ..
}
```

What I noticed is the not: selector excludes all the tables with classes .views-table regardless of using '.main-l .views-table'.

How would I guarantee that only those with threaded classes such as '.main-l .views-table' are excluded, but not those with only .views-table class?

Answer (score 1):

Since `.tbl` is a child of `.main-l` it doesn't work this way. The `:not()` selector only works for the element itself, not for parent elements.

You would have to do this:

```
div:not(.main-l) .tbl {
  ...
}
```

Note that using `div` in css should be avoided, better set a class like `.tbl-container` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.main-1` is parent element you will have to use `not()` on that element to exclude table that is insede it.

```css
table {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

*:not(.main-l) > table {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-l">
  <table class="views-table"></table>
</div>
 <table class="views-table"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Nenad. Would using the asterisk doesn't interfere with performance?

Comment: Well if you know that `.main-1` is going to be div you should use div instead but if it can be any element you need to use `*`, also `>` means that you want to exclude `table` that is direct child of `.main-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are already referring to the `table` but your selector is trying to refer to a class of the outer `div` by using `main-l`.

You can use one of the following to achieve what you are after:

```
table:not(.views-table) {
  background: teal;
}
```

or if you want to be more specific

```
div.main-l table:not(.views-table) {
  background: teal;
}
```

```css
.main-l table {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table:not(.views-table) {
  background: teal;
}

div.main-l table:not(.views-table) {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-l">
  <table class="tbl">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="main-l">
  <table class="views-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="main-l">
  <table class="tbl">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```